# Why is this C function not doing anything?

Tags: c, function, output

I have this function :

```
void change(int **x, int **y){
    x = y;
}

int main(void){

    int x = 10 , y = 15;
    int *p = &x;
    int *q = &y;

    change(&p, &q);

    printf("%d %d", x, y);

    return 0;

}
```

It still outputs the same value.
Why is it that `y` was not assign on `x`?

Comment: You are sending the addresses of p and q not x and y. Use `void change(int *x, int *y)` instead and `*x = *y` not `x = y`

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, but I just want to ask.. I understand I am passing and address but that address also pointing to some address that has value... does the value suppose to come with the pointer?

Comment: You have to dereference the pointer to get to the value.

Comment: You can keep your code and change `x = y` to `**x = **y` if you like

Comment: @NoobProgrammer Did you find an answer to your question? If so, you should consider marking the answer that best fit you as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Arguments to C functions are always passed by value. In order to enable a pass-by-reference behavior, one passes the pointers by value. These pointers can then be dereferenced to access the values outside the function.

```
void change(int **x, int **y){
  x = y;
}
```

Here you are assigning the value of `y` to `x`, which while valid is not what you probably intended: You want the *pointed at* value to change, not the local copy of it. Also one level of indirection suffices. Thus change it to:

```
void change(int *x, int *y){
  *x = *y;
}
```

which is used like this:

```
int a = 2, b = 3;
change(&a, &b);
```

While this works, it's still suboptimal. We are only changing the value pointed at by `x`. The value pointed at by `y` is passed as it without change. So we can save that indirection and pass y by value:

```
void change(int *x, int y){
  *x = y;
}
```

Which is used, as you hopefully can guess now, like this:

```
int a = 3, b = 4;
change(&a, b);
```

Comment: Indirection on `y` is not needed.  Also show how to invoke `change`.

Comment: @chqrlie I assumed he wants to extend it eventually to a `swap` function. But you are right, I should elaborate.

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply, I heard a lot about passing by reference and value.. I google them many times by still dont get the idea.. when is passing by reference is actually useful? since C is passing by value anyway why this feature is allowed and does not give you error?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer This is one example for its use, without pass-by-reference you couldn't change the value of something outside the function from inside it. Also it saves you from copying data whenever a function needs it.
For more information, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: Im sorry, im just not understanding this phrase clearly "without pass-by-reference you couldn't change the value of something outside the function from inside it."...

Comment: @NoobProgrammer we established that when we say f(x), a copy of x is used in the function. if we didn't want a mere copy but the original which was outside the function we need to pass its address (i.e: a reference to it). Check out the link, it has a nice analogy.

Answer (score 1):

in your function ,you only change the copy.
try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void change(int **x, int **y){
    **x = **y;
}

int main(void){

    int x = 10 , y = 15;
    int *p = &x;
    int *q = &y;

    change(&p, &q);

    printf("%d %d", x, y);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say You have variable x stored in location 2015 and y stored in 2016. Now this pointers are stored in locations 2020 and 2021 respectively.
So when you call the function change values are like this:

```
x = 10
y = 15
p = 2015
q = 2016
int **x OR &p = 2020
int **y OR &q = 2021
```

Now what you are doing is like &p = &q, which is nothing but changing values of int **x to 2021. but values of location 2015 and 2016 remains the same.

```
x = 10
y = 15
p = 2015
q = 2016
int **x OR &p = 2021
int **y OR &q = 2021
```

this has nothing to do with values of original `x` or `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example:

```
int x = 10 , y = 15;
int *p = &x;
int *q = &y;
```

Suppose `&x` represents memory address 100 and `&y` represents memory address 104.
Then according to your program `p` will have 100 and `q` will have 104 address pointed.
Forgive me for one more assumption :)
`p` and `q` will also be having their some memory address.
Hence,suppose `&p` represents memory address 200 and `&q` represents memory address 204.

```
change(&p, &q);

void change(int **x, int **y){
x = y;
}
```

Now here `x` will point to `&p` and `y` will point to `&q`.
now using `x=y` will make the x to point to y i.e. `x` and `y` both pointing to 204 memory address ,which by any means cannot change the value of `x`(x=10) and `y`(y=15) in the following function snippet.

```
int main(void){

int x = 10 , y = 15;
int *p = &x;
int *q = &y;

change(&p, &q);

printf("%d %d", x, y);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

int **x, int **y is just a declaration of double pointer.
now x and y will contain the address of pointer p and q.
**x=**y should work.

Comment: "double pointer" is meaningless. "pointer to pointer" is probably what you intended to say.